# joda formatting a LocalDate

Tags: android, jodatime

I have the following code that creates a LocalDate. When i call the toString method on it the output is 2016-01-05.

I would like the date to be in the following format. 05-Jan-2016

```
int dayInt = Integer.parseInt(dayStr);
            int monthInt = Integer.parseInt(monthStr);
            int yearInt = Integer.parseInt(yearStr);

            LocalDate ldt = new LocalDate(yearInt, monthInt, dayInt);

            Log.e(TAG, "LocalDate = " + ldt.toString()); //eg 2016-01-05


            LocalDate localDate2 = LocalDate.parse(ldt.toString(), DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MMM-yy"));
```

.

I get the following exception, does anyone know how i can do this?

Thanks in advance.

```
01-06 14:34:13.903: E/CustomExceptionHandler(8590): stack = java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2016-01-04" is malformed at "16-01-04"
01-06 14:34:13.903: E/CustomExceptionHandler(8590):     at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseLocalDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:821)
01-06 14:34:13.903: E/CustomExceptionHandler(8590):     at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseLocalDate(DateTimeFormatter.java:765)
01-06 14:34:13.903: E/CustomExceptionHandler(8590):     at org.joda.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:178)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `ldt.toString()` produces "2016-01-05".

So your format pattern should be: "**yyyy-MM-dd**" but you start your pattern with the day expecting only two digits (as indicated by the error message).

You say:

> I would like the date to be in the following format. 05-Jan-2016

Then you have to format it (not parse it):

```
String s = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy").withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH).print(ldt);
```

Answer (score 0):

Year is incorrectly formatted.  Change the line:

```
LocalDate localDate2 = LocalDate.parse(ldt.toString(), DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MMM-yy"));
```

to:

```
LocalDate localDate2 = LocalDate.parse(ldt.toString(), DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy"));
```